# Sending serial data from android to a PICAXE microcontroller with usb cable

Tags: android, serial-port, picaxe

I am working on a project that including an android phone that sends simple serial messages to a picaxe microcontroller(14m2) like '1','2','a' etc.
I searched alot on the web, and I only found a way that the android smartphone first "connecting" to the device and "discover" it, the problem is that PICAXE microcontroller is NOT a 'USB' device, and it can't be discoverd by the android, that means the android will not be able to send serial messages to the PICAXE.
if theres any way to send simple pulses from android to PICAXE, please let me know about it.

EDIT: There's any way to do that by connecting the AXE027 download cable with OTG?

Answer (score 0):

I do some project with communicating over serial port. You can use chineese bluetooth adapters (see on ebay arduino bluetooth), those communicate with controllers via Usart and connect to phone by bluetooth. There is sample project Bluetooth chat from google about how to use bluetooth on android. On hardware iside, you can use arduino for receiving data by bluetooth and converting it in format of your controller. You wont have to use any wires

Comment: thank you, but I prefer a wired way because the phone and microcontoller are supposed to be close to each other, and bluetooth connectivity spends the battery faster.